# Magento 2: Custom Module Listing MassDelete Not working [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, module, admin, custom, delete

When i'm trying to delete all records from Listing, By selecting all. Not able to delete.

**app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Messages\MassDelete.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Messages;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;


class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

/**
 * @var Filter
 */
protected $filter;

/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $collectionFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Filter $filter
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 */
public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory) {
    $this->filter = $filter;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Execute action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
 */
public function execute() {

     $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
      $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

      foreach ($collection as $item) {
      $item->delete();
      } 

    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
}
```

It always give blank, when i'm trying to print `$collection`

**[Solution]**

Thanks to this post Magento 2 massaction delete not working

Only missing

Check if you have following line in your `Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection.php` file:

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'module_id';
```

Comment: Please update your Ui component.

Comment: I'm using use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter; how?

Comment: You have declared your Ui component?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I have added whole page code in question. Now please look in to that

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i already solved & put answer, but Marius has deleted my answer

Comment: You should update the answer in your question.

Comment: Added In Question